# select column of a dataframe using udf

Tags: scala, dataframe, select, user-defined-functions

I use spark-shell and want to create a dataframe (df2) from another dataframe (df1) using select and udf. But there is an error when I want to show the df2 ==> df2.show(1)

```
  var df1 = sql(s"select * from table_1")
  val slice = udf ((items: Array[String]) => if (items == null) items 
  else {
     if (items.size <= 20)
       items
     else
       items.slice(0, 20)
  })
  var df2 = df1.select($"col1", slice($"col2"))
```

and the df1 schema is:

```
scala> df1.printSchema
root
  |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
  |-- col2: array (nullable = true)
  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

 scala> df2.printSchema
 root
   |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
   |-- UDF(col2): array (nullable = true)
   |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

error:

```
 Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (array<string>) => array<string>)
```

Comment: is there a stack trace following the error?

Comment: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 20.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 20.0 (TID 56, ... .com, executor 15): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute....  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
 at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used Seq[String] instead of Array[String] in the udf and the issue is resolved.